# Using value of String property inside a [Route()] data annotation in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC project, in a `Action` inside a `Controller` I try to use `STG_Route.ADD`property value inside `[Route()]` data annotation like this :`[Route(STG_Route.ADD)]`
 but **Visual Studio** show me this error :

**An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'AdminController.STG_Route'**

`STG_Route` is an `object` **of a class**, this class is `STG_Route`

`STG_Route` **class code :**

```
public class STG_Route:Routes
{
    public override string ADD => "/STG/Add";
    public override string SHOW => "/STG/Show";
    public override string PROFILE => "/STG/{CODE}";
}
```

`Routes` is another class

Please any help about how can I use value of a `ADD` **property** inside `[Route()]`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't do that - you'll have to devise your own attributes and work with reflection.

Comment: how, please tell me how and massive thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An overriding `property` must be `virtual`, abstract and **STG_Route** inherits from **Routes**, `ADD` cannot be defined as a `const` `string` type, and then you cannot use `STG_Route.ADD` in `Route[()]`. I suggest that you do not let **STG_Route** inherit from **Routes** and assign values ​​directly to `ADD`.

**STG_Route**

```
public class STG_Route
{
    public const string ADD="/STG/Add";
    public const string SHOW= "/STG/Show";
    public const string PROFILE= "/STG/{CODE}";
}
```

**Controller**

```
   public class STGController : Controller
    {
        [Route(STG_Route.ADD)]
        public ActionResult ADD()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```